# infinite while loop in java Named ENTITY RECOGNITION

Tags: java, while-loop, named, named-entity-recognition

In this my first while loop can't break. It decrease the value of j and val

```
val = 69
val = 67
```

after this it as to break but it can't

```
val = 69
val = 67
```

and it repeats again and again
NNP is an Part of speech tag
arr[]= is a collection of tokens
and J gives the index of arr
LName is an array list which gives the database fields and matches with the tokens in first if statement

```
public String NER_Name_LName(String tokens)
{
    // System.out.println("Hello");
    ArrayList<String> LNames = dbconnection1.getTableContents("NER_LName");
    int l=NER_Name.j; 
    
    int val=(l+1), lm=0, p=0;
    String result="";
    String res[] = new String [20];
    
    for(int x=0;x<=(LNames.size()-1);x++)
    {
          //  System.out.println(LNames.size() + "Hello");
        
        if(tokens.equals(LNames.get(x)))
        {
             //System.out.println(NER_Name.arr[val] + val);
            //System.out.println(LNames.get(x) + "Hello");
            while("NNP".equals(NER_Name.arr[val]))
            {
             System.out.println(NER_Name.arr[val]+"lol" + val);
              
                NER_Name.j=NER_Name.j-2;
                val=val-2;
                System.out.println(val+ "after");
            }
           while("NNP".equals(NER_Name.arr[val]))
            {
                res[p]=NER_Name.arr[NER_Name.j];
                p++;
                NER_Name.j=NER_Name.j+2;
                
            }
            
            for (int o=0;o<=(p-1);o++)
            {
                result=result+" "+res[o];
            }
        }
    }  
    //System.out.println(result +"hello");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample input?

Comment: And output , and also name according to Java Naming conventions and indent your code bit more properly Please !

Answer (score 0):

```
 while("NNP".equals(NER_Name.arr[val]))
            {
                res[p]=NER_Name.arr[NER_Name.j];
                p++;
                NER_Name.j=NER_Name.j+2;

            }
```

consider this code, let's say `"NNP".equals(NER_Name.arr[val]) = true` it's enter your loop, executes block, and as `val` and `NER_Name.arr[val]` are not changed, it's executes same block again